# particular Laptop key has no keycode (found with xev from Xorg)

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, thinkpad

that following key should be XF86AudioLowerVolume, but it has not even a defined keycode, i could assign the function of XF86AudioLowerVolume. I've used xev to find that out. I'm using debian Jessie and a Thinkpad T520.

```
FocusOut event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusOut event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

FocusIn event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

for comparison, the output of XF86AudioRaiseVolume

```
KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
    root 0x9a, subw 0x0, time 2905663, (3,321), root:(810,328),
    state 0x0, keycode 123 (keysym 0x1008ff13, XF86AudioRaiseVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

any ideas?